# java get unicode representation string from unicode codepoint

Tags: java, unicode, codepoint

I want to get the string representation `\u` that java uses from an integer codepoint. I looked all over the place and have yet to find a working awnswer for `\ud83e\udd82` which is  . I got the symbol from compiling and decompiling a jar from bytecode viewer. I don't know how it's getting these strings or where from. It's very useful when deving in java to copy a unicode character then paste it in and get the java string version of it. So every class doesn't have to be in utf-8 that uses it.

Comment: Well, those two Unicode escapes are actually UTF-16. [See here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f982/index.htm) for more details.

Comment: @MCEmperor I want to generate the Unicode escape sequences from the unicode character or a codepoint. even though I see that integer codepoint can't represent all of them as it's only equal to integer max value even unassigned it's still missing 7 billion characters

Comment: *So every class doesn't have to be in utf-8 that uses it.* That shouldn't be a problem, I don't think, as Java uses a custom UTF-16 representation of characters, so the escape sequence you showed should work (IF you have the font to print it) irrespective of source encoding. I can't test this as I am scorpion-free, font-wise

Comment: I figured out how to get the string from the codepoint. I am looking into how to get the codepoint from the string dynamically not just at codePoint(0)

Comment: @nullsector76 An integer codepoint can represent *ALL* characters. Why do you think it's missing 7 billion characters?

Comment: @Andreas I misread the amount on the wiki 10 times. I figured it out mostly look at my updated comment. I still don't have it fully working

Comment: @Andreas' code does what you want, does it not?

Comment: @Andreas trying to generate the java unicode escape sequences. java requires it to have 4 characters. I got it working finally. Still not 100% what I wanted. I want to also support converting U+hex as a unicode character to

Comment: What exactly is your goal? If you want to represent that SCORPIAN character in your source code, just do this: `String scorpion = "" ;` or this: `String scorpion = Character.toString( 129_410 ) ; ` (the code point number in decimal is 129410).

Answer (score 5):

([SCORPION](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f982/index.htm)) is Unicode Code Point `1f982`, which is UTF-16 `d83e dd82`, and UTF-8 `f0 9f a6 82`.

To convert the code point integer to Unicode-escaped Java String, run this code:

```java
// Java 11+
int codePoint = 0x1f982;
char[] charArray = Character.toString(codePoint).toCharArray();
System.out.printf("\\u%04x\\u%04x", (int) charArray[0], (int) charArray[1]);
// prints: \ud83e\udd82
```

```java
// Java 1.5+
int codePoint = 0x1f982;
char[] charArray = new String(new int[] { codePoint }, 0, 1).toCharArray();
System.out.printf("\\u%04x\\u%04x", (int) charArray[0], (int) charArray[1]);
// prints: \ud83e\udd82
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can convert unicode characters from a string directly to java's format.

```
    /**
     * return the java unicode string from the utf-8 string
     * TODO: add an option to change the unicode number strings to not just the codepoints
     */
    public static String toUnicodeEsq(String unicode)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        int[] arr = unicode.codePoints().toArray();
        for(int i : arr)
            b.append(toUnicodeEsq(i));
        return b.toString();
    }
    
    public static String toUnicodeEsq(int cp)
    {
        return isAscii(cp) ? "" + (char) cp : Character.isBmpCodePoint(cp) ? "\\u" + String.format("%04x", cp) : "\\u" + String.format("%04x", (int)Character.highSurrogate(cp)) + "\\u" + String.format("%04x", (int)Character.lowSurrogate(cp) );
    }

    public static boolean isAscii(int cp) 
    {
        return cp <= Byte.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

My method doesn't support Unicode Numbers (U+hex) directly but, you can get the string individually one at a time from css, html, and unicode number formats

```
    /**
     * get the codepoint from the unicode number. from there you can convert it to a unicode escape sequence using {@link JavaUtil#getUnicodeEsq(int)}
     * "U+hex" for unicode number
     * "&#codePoint;" or "&#hex;" for html
     * "\hex" for css
     * "hex" for lazyness
     */
    public static int parseUnicodeNumber(String num)
    {
        num = num.toLowerCase();
        if(num.startsWith("u+"))
            num = num.substring(2);
        else if(num.startsWith("&#"))
            return num.startsWith("&#x") ? Integer.parseInt(num.substring(3, num.length() - 1), 16) : Integer.parseInt(num.substring(2, num.length() - 1)); 
        else if(num.startsWith("\\"))
            num = num.substring(1);
        return Integer.parseInt(num, 16);
    }
    
    /**
     * convert a unicode number directly to unicode escape sequence in java
     */
    public static String unicodeNumberToEsq(String num)
    {
        return toUnicodeEsq(parseUnicodeNumber(num));
    }
```

Comment: 1) Since you're using streaming, you should stick with it: `return unicode.codePoints().mapToObj(MyClass::getUnicodeEsq).collect(Collectors.joining());` --- 2) You should combine the `format` calls, i.e. instead of `"\\u" + format("%04x", a) + "\\u" + format("%04x", b)`, you can do `format("\\u%04x\\u%04x", a, b)`

Comment: noticed mine works but, converts standard non unicode characters into Unicode escape sequences

Comment: @Andreas yours would require I believe that it uses vars for each integer call. which would make more lines. also incompatible with java 7 even though I use java 8.

Comment: The code calls `codePoints()`, which was added in Java 8 (couldn't be earlier, since it returns `IntStream`, which was also added in Java 8), so this answer requires Java 8 too. --- Don't know what you mean by "uses vars for each integer call". The stream chain shown in my first comment doesn't use any vars, other than the initial `unicode` parameter, of course.

Comment: A couple of quibbles:
a. Strange naming: 'toUnicodeEsq'? I would go for `toUnicodeEscaped`
b. `isAscii(int cp)` I know what the functionality is here but it's worth saying I think that the body is not correct, since most 'ASCII' encodings extend beyond 7 bits.  More accurate (give or take 'holes') would be `return cp <= 0xFF;`

Comment: @g00se no java only supports the initial 0-127 of `Ascii` you can look up the char of `Ascii` value of 128 and then look at java char of 128 they are not the same. Also anything past an signed byte seems to be unicode

Comment: @nullsector76 Have a look at `System.out.println((char)0xDF);`

Comment: @g00se Ascii extended is what it's called and there is no set in stone table past 127 that I can see so it's unofficial and not reliable anyways. Also everything that is in the extended tables are in unicode. unicode replaced Ascii. so it's not a java issue either

Comment: @g00se `8364` of "€" which is on the Ascii table of 128 doesn't match java's so I don't have to go any further on checking it. they don't match. if a number happens to match it's because it's the same in unicode

Comment: Actually there's no such character encoding in Java as 'ASCII extended' (though that's what various charsets do effectively). Most common encodings that are not UTF-8 go well beyond 0x7F, e.g. Windows-1252, MacRoman, etc.

Comment: Picking on the Euro sign is not a good choice ;) It's a late addition that's been levered in to 'ascii' encodings and is not standardised

Comment: the values don't match up because the format is in unicode. I guess I could check if it's ascii format extended and return true but, that doesn't prove your point. if it's in unicode or anything standard java strings my method is bug free especially when using the unicode methods. nothing supports ASCII extended as it was legacy got replaced with unicode a long time ago. reason to keep only ASCII is file read/write or memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235337/discussion-between-g00se-and-nullsector76).